# why does a jasmine test for angular not call a $resource?

Tags: angularjs, angular-mock

It seems straightforward, but whether I use `$httpBackend` or not, it never returns!

```
    describe('R', function(){
      var Res, http, item, original = {name:"John"};
      beforeEach(function () {
        module('app');
        inject(function ($httpBackend, $resource) {
            http = $httpBackend;
            Res = $resource('/api/user/:user', {user:'@id'});
        });
      });
      beforeEach(function (done) {
        http.when('GET','/api/user/1').respond(original);
        console.log("I GET CALLED");
        Res.get({id:'1'},function (res) {
            console.log("I NEVER GET CALLED");
            item = res;
            done();
        });
      });
      it('should just be true', function(){
        expect(true).toBe(true);
      });
});
```

Why does the second `console.log` line **never** get called?

Comment: Maybe because is asynchronous and the test exit before the $resource can finish the request?

Comment: I wish. I tried this both with jasmine 2.0 and mocha, both of which support the `beforeEach(function(done){})` syntax. Both of them time out on the 2000ms timeout on the tests. It just never responds!

Comment: Try the jasmine.Ajax.withMock feature or with the jasmine.createSpy feature

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Untold hours spent figuring this out (OK, a lot of it with timing issues where jsfiddle sometimes gives an "undeclared variable describe" error which sidetracked me). In short:

```
    http.when('GET','/api/user/1').respond(original);
    console.log("I GET CALLED");
    Res.get({id:'1'},function (res) {
        console.log("I NEVER GET CALLED");
        item = res;
        done();
    });
    http.flush();
```

Sigh...